# Modify json string from response in scala

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

I am trying to parse json using lift json in scala which I received from post call as a response string and update fields in json and then make put call with the modified json.

```
Response string  {"id":x,"status":"xxx","Ip":xxxx}
```

I want to modify status

```
val response=Post()
    val res = raw"""$response"""
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    case class JsonData(id: Int, status:String,Ip:String)
      val json = parse(res)
        val m = json.extract[JsonData]
    println(m.id)
```

Exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/thoughtworks/paranamer/Paranamer  at
>   net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.net$liftweb$json$Extraction$$mkMapping$1(Extraction.scala:194)
>     at
>   net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.net$liftweb$json$Extraction$$extract0(Extraction.scala:199)
>     at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:43)    at
>   net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$JValue.extract(JsonAST.scala:312)    at
>   mytest.TestApi$.main(TestApi.scala:38)    at
>   mytest.TestApi.main(TestApi.scala) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.paranamer.Paranamer
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 6 more

Comment: Looks like you have some problems with build configuration. Share your build.sbt

Comment: Such errors usually stem from version incompatibilities between your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks..I need to add paranamer jar